# How do I explicitly disable DNS servers in dhcpd.conf?

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp

My `dhcpd.conf` looks like this currently:

```
interface wlan0

static ip_address=192.168.0.200/24
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1
```

The system is going to be on an offline network. Can I remove the `domain_name_servers` line safely? Will it do what I expect? Is there a default domain name servers setting?

(It does seem to be okay, but I'm not sure how to test)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you remove the `domain_name_servers` line, your dhcpcd client daemon will no set a `nameserver` line in the file `/etc/resolv.conf`, so you will not have any default resolver. Then, for instance, if you ping some host with a host name, you will get immediately an error, since no DNS request would be done:

```
% ping this_is_a_host_name
ping: unknown host this_is_a_host_name
```